# How to improve performance when state update in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing application with grid of text inputs.

In redux store I have a "content" state which consists of rows, and the row consists of 20 cells. Each cell has text input, with onChange() the content state in store is updated. Number of rows can grow up to 100 and when there are many rows updating it is very slow. It seems my code is not optimised but I can't find what is wrong. Below is how it's done currently (removed too much detail). Could anyone point out what I should fix?

Types:

```
Content:Row[]
Row:{cells:string[]}
```

Grid component:

```
const Grid = () => {
  const content = //getContentFromStore

  return (
    <div>
      {content.map((_, rowIndex) => (
        <Row rowIndex={rowIndex} key={`row_${rowIndex}`} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

}
```

Row component:

```
const Row = ({ rowIndex }) => {
  const row = //getContentFromStore[rowIndex]

  return (
    <div>
        {row.cells.map((_, colIndex) => (
          <div key={`(${rowIndex},${colIndex})`}>
            <Cell rowIndex={rowIndex} colIndex={colIndex} />
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Cell component:

```
const Cell = ({ rowIndex, colIndex }) => {
  const content = //getContentFromStore
  const row = content[rowIndex]
  const cell = row.cells[colIndex]

  return (
      <TextInput
        value={cell}
        // TODO: update is slow when there is very many rows
        onChange={e => dispatch(updateCell({ rowIndex, colIndex, text: e.target.value }))}
      />
  )
}
```

UpdateCell function in reducer:

```
updateCell: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ rowIndex: number; colIndex: number; text: string }>) => {
      const { rowIndex, colIndex, text } = action.payload
      state.content[rowIndex].cells[colIndex] = text
}
```

Comment: why you rendrer all rows at all ? if user can view only some part of tem. Just dynamic row render by rendering next one when user scroll down. (btw if you have table just use table, th, td etc). And set debounce on this input. Why you expect that browswer will render so many rows that quick as user will write. it is not  possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there might be multiple reasons for performance issues and the reason might depend on what's happening on the `onChange` event, however the one thing that lies on the surface is the non-performant usage of [react keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

In a nutshell, manipulations with rows might be treated badly from the state of performance when matching virtual DOM row items and the browser DOM to map them to each other especially on addition and removal operations.

Even though that's not a guarantee for solving the issue of yours at least try changing the keys from array indexes to a property that uniquely identifies a row (`id` presumably in majority of the cases).

Types:

```
Content:Row[]
Row:{id: string, cells:{id: string, value: string}[]}
// for Row - `id` or any other property or a combination of properties that uniquely identify the row but not an the array index 
// for Cell - most likely there is no `id` for a cell but each cell I guess could somehow be distinguishable from other cells by the title of the column header at least

// e.g. row1 {id: '1', cells: [ {id: 'title', value: 'Foo'}, { id: 'description', value: 'Foo description'  } ] }
//      row2 {id: '2', cells: [ {id: 'title', value: 'Bar'}, { id: 'description', value: 'Bar description'  } ] }
```

Grid component:

```
const Grid = () => {
const content = //getContentFromStore
  return (
   <div>
    {content.map((row) => {

    const {id} = row 
    <Row rowId={id} key={`row_${id}`} />

    })}
   </div>
  )}}
```

Row component:

```
const Row = ({ rowId }) => {
    const row = // getContentFromStore(rowId) // try to get content by the identifier  
    return (
    <div>
        {row.cells.map((cell) => {
        const {id} = cell        

        <div key={`(${rowId},${id})`}>
          <Cell rowId={rowId} cellId={id} />
       </div>
    })}
</div>
)}
```

Cell component:

```
const Cell = ({ rowId, cellId }) => {
const content = // getContentFromStore
const row = getContentFromStore(rowId)
const cell = row.cells.find(cell => cell.id === cellId)


return (
  <TextInput
    value={cell.value}
    onChange={e => dispatch(updateCell({ rowIndex, colIndex, text:
    e.target.value }))}
/>
)}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Adding id to row and cell didn't help improving update speed. I chose to have local state in the cell component and only update central state onBlur instead of onChange. Moving focus becomes slower but better than slowing down on every typing.